# Is @SafeVarargs an appropriate annotation for this method?

Tags: java, variadic-functions, type-safety

I have a bit of Java code (using the Guava `ImmutableList` class):

```
@Nonnull
public static <E extends Event> UserHistory<E> forUser(long id, E... events) {
    List<E> list = ImmutableList.copyOf(events);
    return new BasicUserHistory<E>(id, list);
}
```

I am getting the usual heap pollution warnings that come with a method like this.  Since my method is not doing any modifications of `events`, it cannot *introduce* a heap pollution. However, if (because of erasure) a client of this method calls it with a bad `events` array, it seems that it can propagate a heap polution through itself.

If I annotate it with `@SafeVarargs`, I still get a warning in it (suppressable with `@SuppressWarnings("varargs")`).  But reading the Java documentation on [heap pollution](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/nonReifiableVarargsType.html#heap_pollution), I am a little unclear as to the correct set of annotations on this method.

I also note that `ImmutableList.copyOf` is *not* marked as `@SafeVarargs` (though this could just be a compatibility issue), but `Arrays.asList` is.

So, my question: is `@SafeVarargs` an appropriate annotation for this method, given that it will not encounter a `ClassCastException`, but might propagate an improperly-checked array through to the final parameterized type and allow a `ClastCastException` in client code?

I believe, based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14252221/1385039), that it is safe, since the code does not do anything that depends on the type of `events` itself, only on the type of its elements. Is that a correct application of the guidance?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, `@SafeVarargs` should be appropriate, because the only thing that is done with `events` is to pass it to `ImmutableList.copyOf()`, which (in my understanding of that method) does not depend on the runtime type of that array.

`ImmutableList.copyOf()` *should* be annotated with `@SafeVarargs`, but 
it isn't (maybe for backwards compatibility or they haven't noticed it). When your non-reifiable varargs method passes the varargs parameter to another method that may potentially depend on the runtime type of the array, then (for reasons I don't fully understand, but is the subject of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28914088/java-warning-varargs-method-could-cause-heap-pollution-from-non-reifiable-varar)) it gives you a varargs warning for that call. This can be suppressed with `@SuppressWarnings("varargs")`.