# @SafeVarargs not suppressing warning on Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, variadic-functions, type-safety

I have this method:

```
 @SafeVarargs
 public static MyClass getInstance(String myString,
        Class<? extends MyInterface>... classes) {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new MyClass();
    }

    if (classes != null) {
        for (Class<? extends MyInterface> c : classes) {
            MyInterface mi = instantiateClass(c);
            mi.myMethod();
        }
    }
    return instance;
}
```

Calling this method generates this warning on Eclipse:

```
 Type safety: A generic array of Class<? extends MyInterface> is created for a varargs parameter
```

Since I'm working on a framework I'd like to get rid of this warning without annotating the client code. To do that I've annotated my method with @SafeVarargs, but I keep getting the warning.

Maybe I'm not understanding this annotation? Shouldn't it suppress the warning?

Thank you.

Comment: That *should* work, but you haven't shown where you applied the annotation. Provide the exact code.

Comment: @chrylis I've added the annotation

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47949197/9304999