# Why @SafeVarargs doesn't suppress the warning?

Tags: java

Here is the code:

```
class Foo<T> {
  private final T[] array;
  @SafeVarargs
  Foo(T... items) {
    this.array = items;
  }
}
```

I'm getting:

```
[WARNING] Varargs method could cause heap pollution 
from non-reifiable varargs parameter items
```

What's wrong with my assignment? How to fix that? `@SuppressWarnings` is not an option, since I want this constructor to be truly "safe."

```
$ javac -version
javac 1.8.0_40
```

Comment: Use a `List<T>` instead; invoke with `new Foo(Arrays.asList(...))`.

Comment: Not getting any warnings with javac or Netbeans or intellij. Using eclipse?

Comment: @assylias I compile with `-Xlint`

Comment: I don't see that warning with Eclipse (Neon) either. Which version of javac is this?

Comment: @assylias this is how it works: `javac -Werror -Xlint -Xlint:-varargs Main.java`

Comment: @yegor256 Mmm - actually I was compiling with maven and getting no warning (or with Netbeans and Intellij) but I do get the warning with javac if I compile the file alone. Not sure why - ignore my previous comments.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java warning: Varargs method could cause heap pollution from non-reifiable varargs parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28914088/java-warning-varargs-method-could-cause-heap-pollution-from-non-reifiable-varar)

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/non-reifiable-varargs.html#suppressing, besides documenting the behavior, provides an example with three differently annotated calls to a vararg method.

Comment: @yegor256 I launched your code and I didn't saw any warning during compilation my javac -version: `javac 1.8.0_131`

Comment: @rukavitsya have you run it with `Xlint`?

Comment: @assylias with `-Xlint` I got this warning message, but the spec says that - `-Xlint` `"enable all recommended warnings"` and this option can simply overcome `SafeVarargs` annotation.

Comment: @rukavitsya No -Xlint won't show any warnings if you use the appropriate annotations.

Comment: @assylias but it's a fact that I have the warning with `-Xlint` and don't have it without this option.

Comment: @rukavitsya Where does it say that `Xlint` "overcomes" `SafeVarag`? Did you just guess and try to push it as fact?

Comment: @Vince Emigh No, it's just a guess, as result of running javac with and without `Xlint` option on my machine.

Comment: @rukavitsya Yes that's the point: -Xlint shows the warnings - and if you think one of the warnings is not relevant, you can remove it with an annotation, like `@SafeVarargs`. And the question here is: why doesn't the annotation remove the warning.

Comment: @yegor256 I checked this issue on latest version of jdk  `1.8.0_131` and compile test class that creates instance of Foo uses this command `javac -Xlint:all -cp //classpath// TestFoo.java` and get no warnings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that I was using `-Xlint` command line `javac` parameter. I found out that I have to compile it with the following params:

```
javac -Werror -Xlint -Xlint:-varargs
```

That's it.

Answer (score 2):

From the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/SafeVarargs.html):

> Applying this annotation to a method or constructor *suppresses unchecked warnings about a **non-reifiable variable arity (vararg) type*** and *suppresses unchecked warnings about parameterized array creation **at call sites***.

The first statement tells us `@SafeVarargs` suppresses unchecked warnings about:

- non-reifiable type for your varargs
- parameterized array creations when you call the method

In your case, `@SafeVarargs` is suppressing the warning on `T... items`. Your warning is occuring on `this.array = items;`.

---

From the [JLS §9.6.4.7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.6.4.7):

> The annotation `@SafeVarargs` has *non-local* effects because it **suppresses unchecked warnings at method invocation expressions** in addition to an *unchecked* warning **pertaining to the declaration of the variable arity method itself**.
>
> ---
>
> In contrast, the annotation `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` has local effects because it only suppresses unchecked warnings pertaining to the declaration of a method.

Comment: I think that last two quotes don't related to *"Your warning is occuring on `this.array = items;`"*. You didn't explain why `varargs` warning is thrown when we refer the varargs parameter inside the method even though there is `@SafeVarargs`.

Answer (score 1):

Joshua Bloch explains this in Effective Java (25s chapter):

> The prohibition on generic array creation can be annoying. It means,
>   for example, that it’s not generally possible for a generic type to
>   return an array of its element type (but see Item 29 for a partial
>   solution). It also means that you can get confusing warnings when
>   using varargs methods (Item 42) in combination with generic types.
>   This is because every time you invoke a varargs method, an array is
>   created to hold the varargs parameters. If the element type of this
>   array is not reifiable, you get a warning. There is little you can do
>   about these warnings other than to suppress them (Item 24), and to
>   avoid mixing generics and varargs in your APIs.

The reason for this message is described in [spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/non-reifiable-varargs.html#heap_pollution), in [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/non-reifiable-varargs.html#suppressing) part of spec, there is similar example (with class ArrayBuilder and different combinations of annotation usage)

Like alternative, try to use mix of SafeVarargs and SuppressWarnings annotations

```
@SafeVarargs
@SuppressWarnings( "varargs" )
```

HTH

Comment: You are explaining the **warning**. You are **not at all** answering the question why the **annotation** does not **suppress** the warning. But maybe I am wrong, and some of the upvoters can explain why they think this answer **answers** the question.

Comment: `@SuppressWarnings` is not an option, since all other calls of this ctor will still produce the same warning.