# Correct way to avoid varargs "method could cause heap pollution from non-reifiable varargs parameter iterators" in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, variadic-functions

Let's take this sample Java method:

```java
public static <E> HashSet<E> createHashSet(final E... elements) {
  final HashSet<E> hashSet = new HashSet<E>(elements.length);
  java.util.Collections.addAll(hashSet, elements);
  return hashSet;
}
```

If I'm compiling with Java 17 using `-Xlint:all`, I get the following warning for the method signature:

> `Varargs method could cause heap pollution from non-reifiable varargs parameter iterators`

Eclipse 2022-09 suggests using `@SafeVarargs`. And indeed Java's own `java.util.Collections.addAll(…)` itself uses `@SafeVarargs`! Yet when I add it to the method signature, `javac` gives me the same warning, only further down in the `java.util.Collections.addAll(…)` line.

The answers to [java warning: Varargs method could cause heap pollution from non-reifiable varargs parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28914088) suggest additionally using `@SuppressWarnings("varargs")` on the method for IntelliJ. And indeed when I use both `@SafeVarargs` and `@SuppressWarnings("varargs")` together, the lint warning goes away with `javac`. However Eclipse says this annotation value `"varargs"` is unsupported.

Eclipse also suggests using `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`. If I add *only* `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` to the method, then the warning goes away both in Eclipse and in `javac` with linting! So it would seem that a single `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` is the way to go.

But is it? https://stackoverflow.com/a/47949197 seems to indicate that the way to go for IntelliJ is `@SafeVarargs` and `@SuppressWarnings("varargs")` together, and https://stackoverflow.com/a/44675766 seems to agree in general. And the source code for Java uses `@SafeVarargs`.

Is Eclipse incorrect in forcing me to use `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` instead of `@SafeVarargs` and `@SuppressWarnings("varargs")` together? I have opened [Eclipse Issue #453](https://github.com/eclipse-jdt/eclipse.jdt.core/issues/453) to try to get more answers.

### Note on duplicates

Note that [java warning: Varargs method could cause heap pollution from non-reifiable varargs parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28914088) does not seem to be a duplicate; it is about avoiding this warning on IntelliJ. The solution there does not work for Eclipse.

Comment: According to https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/SafeVarargs.html Eclipse does it right.

Comment: Could you explain further? The `SafeVarArgs` API documentation you mention says that if a method is annotated with `@SafeVarArgs` but the body performs unsafe operations, the compiler may issue a further warning, but it doesn't say how to suppress those warnings. `javac` and others say to _add_ a `@SuppressWarnings("varargs")` annotation. Eclipse expects us to _remove_ `@SafeVarArgs` and _instead_ add `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`. But [javac Xlint](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/specs/man/javac.html) does list `varargs` in the docs.

Comment: For me both works fine in Eclipse, `@SafeVarargs` or `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`. `@SafeVarargs` Javadoc: _" Applying this annotation to a method [...] suppresses unchecked warnings"_. You said _" when I add it to the method signature, `javac` gives me the same warning, only further down in the `java.util.Collections.addAll(…)` line."_ which sound to me like the opposite of that. Does `javac` behave the same in all Java versions?

Comment: "For me both works fine in Eclipse, `@SafeVarargs` or `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`." Ah, I think what you might have missed in the description is that in Java 17 I'm compiling with `-Xlint:all`. That's when it turns out that `@SafeVarargs` is insufficient; it only applies to the _method parameters_, not things javac feels are unsafe it the method body. That's where the `@Suppresswarnings("varargs")` comes in, which Eclipse doesn't recognize. See the [Xlint keys](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/specs/man/javac.html).

Comment: See also [Eclipse Bug 344783](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=344783), which (10 years ago!) said the same thing I'm saying, but somehow fell between the cracks; as well as [Eclipse Issue #453](https://github.com/eclipse-jdt/eclipse.jdt.core/issues/453), which I just opened. I think the issue is simply that Eclipse needs to recognize `@SuppressWarnings("varargs")` for non-reifiable varargs usage within a method—just as Oracle does, as OpenJDK does, and IntellJ does (to my understanding).

Comment: If you want to reproduce this, use [this `pom.xml`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/globalmentor/globalmentor-root/main/pom.xml) as your Maven POM parent, set `<maven.compiler.release>17</maven.compiler.release>` in your project POM, and compile the example code in the description using `-P lint` to turn on linting. (I don't know what Java <17 does.)

Comment: Why do you think Eclipse needs to recognize `@SuppressWarnings("varargs")` when the documentation says those are _unchecked_ warnings? Eclipse sticks to the Java specification and does not try to mimic `javac`. So please refer to the documentation which says that it must be `@SuppressWarnings("varargs")` and not `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`. Please provide a pull request for what you want.

Comment: I guess one of my biggest doubts is why Eclipse wants me to remove `@SafeVarargs` if I add `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`. Even the JDK uses `@SafeVarargs`! Eclipse doesn't seem to understand that there are two levels of varargs-related problems: one in the method parameters (the incoming arguments) (`@SafeVarargs)`, and another in an invocation within the method body (`@SuppressWarnings("varargs")`). Eclipse would have me use `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` and remove `@SafeVarargs` altogether. Saying that `javac` got it wrong is also unsatisfying (although it's certainly possible).

Answer (score 1):

As solution use **`@SafeVarargs @SuppressWarnings({"all", "varargs"})`**.

Detailed explanation:

#### Why is there a *potential heap pollution* warning here?

Your method has varargs parameters of a generic type (`E`) which means that the elements will be an array of type `Object[]` at runtime which can lead to heap pollution. Heap pollution can also happen when assigning a more general type array to a more specific type array, as in the following example, but when using varargs it is less obvious as the `Object[]` array is implicitly created. The [Javadoc for @SafeVarargs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/SafeVarargs.html) gives an example where the semantic error can be spotted when looking closely, but the example given by [Baeldung - Java @SafeVarargs Annotation](https://www.baeldung.com/java-safevarargs#thesafevarargs-annotation) the error is not obvious at all, isn't it? Hence the warning.

```
String[] strings= { "a", "b" };
Object[] objects= strings;
objects[0]= Integer.valueOf(23); // heap pollution
```

#### How to solve this warning?

Since the **Java compiler cannot compute** whether the **varargs of generic types** are used **semantically correctly** (see [halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem)), it is your job to check this.

[The varargs usage is safe if and only if](https://www.baeldung.com/java-varargs#1-safe-usage):

- **No storing** of objects of a wrong type in the implicitly created varargs array
- The implicitly created varargs array **does not escape** out of the method

If the varargs of a generic type are **not semantically correctly** used, **fix your code. Otherwise, add `@SafeVarargs`** (in Java 5 and 6 `@SuppressWarnings` has to be added instead, since [`@SafeVarargs`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/SafeVarargs.html) has been introduced later in Java 7). Please note, in contrast to `@SafeVarargs` (`@Retention(RUNTIME)`), `@SuppressWarnings` (`@Retention(SOURCE)`) will be lost when shipping your code as binary.

In your example the varargs  of the generic type `E` are safe: you don't store anything in the implicitly created varargs array, nor does the implicitly created varargs array escape the method. So the right thing is to **add `@SafeVarargs`** to the method (since [`@SafeVarargs`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/SafeVarargs.html) has been added to Java 7, but the [`TYPE_PARAMETER` target](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/annotation/ElementType.html#TYPE_PARAMETER) has been added in Java 8, it cannot be added directly to the varargs parameter, but only to the method).

#### Why does `javac` gives a warning even with `@SafeVarargs`?

`javac` with `-Xlint:varargs` checks whether `@SafeVarargs` has been correctly added. In the following example `javac -Xlint:varargs` shows five warnings. The warning of the varargs escaping to another `@SafeVarargs` method (see `3`), as in your case, does not seem correct to me.

```
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// warning: [varargs] Redundant SafeVarargs annotation. Varargs element type String is reifiable.
@SafeVarargs 
static <E> void foo(String... elements1) { }

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// warning: [varargs] Varargs method could cause heap pollution from non-reifiable varargs parameter elements2
@SafeVarargs 
static <E> E[] foo(E[] elements1, int i, E... elements2) {
    Object[] objects1= elements1;
    objects1[0]= new Object();
    Object[] objects2= elements2; // 1
    objects2[0]= new Object();
    array(elements1);
    array(elements2); // 2
    safeVararg(elements1);
    safeVararg(elements2); // 3 false positive?
    return i > 0
           ? elements1
           : elements2; // 4
}

@SafeVarargs
static <E> void safeVararg(E... elements) { }

static <E> void array(E[] elements) { }
```

The checks and thus the `@SuppressWarnings` keys differ in [`javac`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/specs/man/javac.html#option-Xlint-custom) and in the [Eclipse compiler for Java (ecj)](https://help.eclipse.org/latest/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/tasks/task-suppress_warnings.htm). **In Eclipse** there seems to be **no equivalent to `javac`'s varargs check**/`@SuppressWarnings` yet (no problems are shown for the above example in Eclipse 2022-09).

Unfortunately, `javac` ignores `@SuppressWarnings("all")` which seems a bug of `javac`. So `@SuppressWarnings("all")` cannot be used here as workaround, but `@SafeVarargs @SuppressWarnings({"all", "varargs"})` makes both compilers happy.

See also: [Eclipse JDT core issues #453](https://github.com/eclipse-jdt/eclipse.jdt.core/issues/453) (reported by you)